# Game maker Studio pro 64 bits architecture for android requisites

Tags: game-maker-studio-1.4

Now Game maker Studio Pro is legacy so don't have more updates. Google Play Store have a new requisite to compile the apk on 64 bits architecture, but on Game maker Studio Pro it seems to be only the x86 option. How could I Compile with 64 bits architecture on that legacy version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.4 is legacy and does not support 64-bit architecture so you'll need to get hacky with it if you want it to work. I would take a look at this Reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/gamemaker/comments/am4gwg/will_game_maker_14_be_adding_in_64_bit/
A user said:

> so technically, you could build your game as YYC with 1.4.9999 and then change the references in the project libyoyo to the 64 bit versions

Idk how accurate that is but it's worth a shot.